# Buildmaster throws System.IO.PathTooLongException when deploying an artifact?

Tags: buildmaster

When I try and deploy a artifact from a team city build on build master I get  `System.IO.PathTooLongException` but none of my files have more than 260 characters.

What do I do now?

Comment: Thanks very much for help, do you have possible links to any resources?

Answer (score 0):

Support for paths greater than 260 characters was added in v4.5 of the software so this should no longer be an issue.